# Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined when use reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying to pass values from API to state but always give this error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined
selectIds**

I am using the 'reduxjs/toolkit' I try everything but still continue that error could you please help me

this is a code from the Slic file

```
export const getListNamesDictionary = createAsyncThunk('dictionary/names/getNames', async () => {
 try {
     const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:6005/api/lookup/list-name');
     const data = await response.data;
     // dispatch(getNames(data));
     debugger;
     console.log(data);
     return data;
 } catch (error) {
     return console.error(error.message);
 }
});
const namesAdapter = createEntityAdapter({});
```

and the Slic :

```
const namesDictionarySlice = createSlice({
   name: 'names',
   initialState: {
       names: []
   },
   reducers: {
       
   },
   extractors: {
       [getListNamesDictionary.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
           state.entities.push(action.payload);
       }
   }
});
export const { selectAll: selectNamesDictionary } = namesAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.data);
```

and this code from component where I need to dispatch the action

```
const names = useSelector(selectNamesDictionary);
useEffect(() => {
        // dispatch(getListNamesDictionary()).then(() => setLoading(false));
        dispatch(getListNamesDictionary()).then(() => setLoading(false));
    }, [dispatch]);
```

**any suggesting why that error? and thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Slic function, I make a mistake in writing, I most write  'extraReducer' but I wrote "extractors"  :D

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the entity adapter properly.  It expects to manage a state in the form:

```
{
  ids: [1, 2],
  entities: {
    1: {/*...*/},
    2: {/*...*/}
  }
}
```

Your `names` slice doesn't match that shape.  But that's an easy fix as the `namesAdapter` provides all of the needed tools.  Quick rundown of errors to fix:

- property name `extractors` should be `extraReducers`
- `state.entities.push` needs to be replaced with an adapter function
- `initialState` needs to have properties `ids` and `entities`
- selectors need to target the correct location

```
const namesAdapter = createEntityAdapter({});

const namesDictionarySlice = createSlice({
  name: "names",
  initialState: namesAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getListNamesDictionary.fulfilled]: namesAdapter.upsertMany
  }
});
```

This fixes the first three bullets. Regarding the reducer, it might make more sense if you write it out like this, but it does the same thing.

```
[getListNamesDictionary.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  namesAdapter.upsertMany(state, action)
}
```

The last bullet point is the cause of the specific error message the you posted:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined

It actually seems like `state.data` is `undefined`.  Is this `namesDictionarySlice` being used to control the `data` property of your root state?  If it is something else, like `state.names`, then you need to change your selectors to `namesAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.names)`.

If your store looks like this:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    names: namesReducer
  }
});
```

You would want:

```
export const { selectAll: selectNamesDictionary } = namesAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => state.names // select the entity adapter data from the root state
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem still persists.
The problem is that state does not communicate with the payload. Look at the pictures from Redux Tools dev
Here is the Action and loading the data very well
https://ibb.co/8BWTSrK
but here the state does not see the payload,I tried  your way also but still do not work 
and state still empty
https://ibb.co/q9krmcp

Comment: oooo I found my mistake is a printing mistake I wrote a "extractors"  inside the slice and most be extraReducer :D

 const namesDictionarySlice = createSlice({
   name: 'names',
   initialState: {
       names: []
   },
   reducers: {
       
   },
   extractors: {
       [getListNamesDictionary.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
           state.entities.push(action.payload);
       }
   }
});